# Updating data inside an infinite loop in c

Tags: c, infinite-loop

I have a function that displays the number for a 7segment display using multiplexing. And from what i know on how to multiplex you will need to enable the fisrt segment you wish to display while disabling the second, and to print the second segment you will need to disable the first and enable the second, and you will need to place this in an infinite loop so that the data will successfully print.

Now my problem is that the data to be displayed is changing, and needs to be updated constantly but in my code i cannot update the data inside the infinite loop thus it is stuck in its first value recieved.

My codes:

For my main function:

```
     Void main(){
      while(1){
        displaytemp(TEMP);
       }
      }

Void displaytemp(int temp){
 While(1){
  Int tens = temp/10;
  Int ones = temp%10;
  Print(tens);
  Enable first 7seg
  Disable second 7seg
  Delay();
  Print(ones);
  Disable first 7seg
  Enable second 7seg
  }

  }
```

The TEMP is from an interrupt source and is constantly updating if i dont place it inside the infinite loop but it can only display 1 digit.  TEMP is temperature of the room in whole number.

Comment: You need delay between `Print()`s.  Example: Add `Delay();` before `Print(tens);`

Comment: Ill give that a try. Thanks. Though why is my delay between the tens and ones not updating then?

Comment: The details of the post are still a bit unclear, but it seems you code is operating as desired except your the display of 1 digit is so quick, your eye does not see it before it has gone back to the other digit.

Comment: @chux there are 2 7segment display, 1 for the tens value and the other for the ones. I am able to display the values using the code above. But it is not updating. It is stuck in the first value it recieved so when the room temperature changes it wont display the new value. Im thinking of calling the displaytemp(TEMP) function again inside the infinite loop. Is that a good practice or even correct.

Comment: @magicianIam: So you're displaying alternate digits very quickly?

Comment: Yes since that is multiplexing. :)

Comment: What's the code? It's tagged as C, but doesn't look like C with upper-cased keywords (eg: Void), odd indentation, and lines like "Enable first 7seg".

Comment: @Anonymous sorry about that. Im using my phone atm. It is in c. I just opted some of the hardware declaration

Comment: @magicianIam Perhaps you should wait until you're at a keyboard so you can ask the question without errors that you already know about?

Comment: I should have pointed those out. My bad. And its been bothering me for a while now so i really needed some answers.

Comment: @magicianlam If you're on your phone you presumably can't test and react to the answers either.  Please always ask your questions from a proper environment, using proper tools.  I myself had to go and look to try and retag this and discover what kind of odd variant of C for hardware controlling you were using.  Always give your best efforts in the questions...and respect those who are trying to give their best efforts in answers.  I don't often downvote, but am going to symbolically do so here as a way of saying "you should have known better".  :-/

Comment: Actually i can identify and know the outcome of the code. Since that is a basic skill for developers. And that is why i was able to know that the answer was a great idea since i my self didnt really think of using a parameter as an identifier. And i dont mind your downvote

Comment: @magicianlam Well, the downvote is for making people puzzle and research and have to ask you "what is this?" after deliberately writing non-C without explaining it.  The question of if it's okay to ask pseudocode questions in general--*when presented clearly as pseudocode*--is a separate issue.  It's a slippery slope, because then you're "making up a language" to ask your question...which rules out a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  It would be a very rare circumstance where making up one's own language for a question is a good idea, and this wouldn't be one of those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got 2 infinite loops - the inner loop (within displaytemp) blocks the first. Here's one way of handling it:

```
void main(){
  while(true){
      int temperature = get_temp();
      display_digit(first, temp/10);
      display_digit(second, temp%10);
  }
}

void display_digit(segment, int digit){
  if (segment == first) enable_7seg(first);
  else disable_7seg(first);
  if (segment == first) enable_7seg(second);
  else disable_7seg(second);

  Print(digit);
  Delay();
}
```

Comment: This is actually a great idea. Ill try this ones i get home. Thank you.